# Pasting embedded links into Slack is not working

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste, slack, paste

I need my code to paste an embedded link into a Slack message and a Gmail draft.

With the code below, a Gmail draft accepts the paste correctly, but a Slack message won't accept the paste at all.

```
const htmlContent = 'Hello <a href="https://world.com">world</a>';

const blob = new Blob([htmlContent], { type: 'text/html' });

const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blob });

navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Copied to clipboard.');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed:', error);
  });
```

How can I change the code so that an embedded link can be pasted into both a Slack message and a Gmail draft?